# Validating method object argument

Tags: java, spring

I have a DTO class with fields that either have javax or custom constraints put on them so everytime I hit this endpoint I am guaranteed to take in data that meets my requirements.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<SomeResource> create(@Valid @RequestBody SomeDTO someDTO)
```

For reasons I do not want to go into, I am forced to validate this incoming data elsewhere (preferably in a separate service method) so I have tried doing:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<SomeResource> create(@RequestBody SomeDTO someDTO) { 
     someService.validate(someDTO);
}
```

where the called method's signature is defined as

```
 validate(@Valid SomeDTO someDTO)
```

Though I quickly figured out this does not actually do any other argument validation other than user input. With the Spring annotations not being particularly helpful, are there any other annotations out there that can validate an object passed in as a parameter to ensure the constraints are not violated?

Comment: First of, second snippet is not valid Java. Second, you need to elaborate on "not as easy as it appears" part. Your post contain no actual problem, just a vague mention that a problem may indeed exists somewhere.

Comment: I have edited the original post accordingly

Comment: Still there are errors

Comment: One's too reliant on IDEs these days. Should be fine now

Comment: are you gonna pass a valid entity to the `validate` method?

Comment: All that is really being done is redirecting user input to the method taking in the object as a parameter. As much as the @Valid annotation works for the endpoint method it does not for the service one called immediately afterwards.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-method